# Установка miniconda внутри docker

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, dockerfile

Не получается выполнить скрипт установки miniconda внутри Docker

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN sh Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Получаю бесконечный вывод из

```
>>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью следующего Dockerfile можно установить anaconda

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS BUILD


RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install make python3.7 python3-pip git curl libgl1-mesa-glx

# Install miniconda to /miniconda
RUN curl -LO http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -p /miniconda -b
RUN rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
ENV PATH=/miniconda/bin:${PATH}
RUN conda update -y conda

# Python packages from conda
RUN conda install -c anaconda -y python=3.7
RUN conda install -c anaconda -y \
    pip
```